# continuation in compiler flag of make file

Tags: makefile

is there any way to have multi-line compiler flags in a make file?
I tried the following:

```
EXECUTABLE= test
SOURCES= test.f90
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES: .f90=.o)

FFLAGS= -fast -vec-report=3 -profile-functions \    # enable for profiling
        -profile-loops=all -profile-loops-report=2    
FC=/opt/intel/bin/ifort

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

clean:
    rm -f core *~ *.o $(EXECUTABLE)
```

but it cuts off the second line of FFLAGS

Comment: Does it work without that line comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had the right idea. You just then shot yourself in the foot.

A trailing <kbd>\</kbd> is the correct solution you just then proceeded to put more data on the line thus negating the "trailing" part of the continuation marker. Move that comment and it will work.

Comment: any idea why moving the comment to the second line also doesn't work?

Comment: Moved where exactly? At the end of the current second line should work fine. As a new second line can't continue the assignment but can continue the comment.